# Java generilization is demanding implicit type instead wildcard

Tags: java, generics

I have class:
`public class WebDriverHighlighterListener extends AbstractWebDriverEventListener implements WebDriverEventListener {`
And code [image]

Why does it demand implicit type when I have constructor with wildcard?

Comment: Why are you messing around with screenshots instead of just doing a textual copy&paste of the relevant code fragments?

Comment: Does AbstractWebDriverEventListener extend WebDriverEventListener?

Comment: AbstractWebDriverEventListener implement WebDriverEventListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different issues. Before Java 8, the expression `Arrays.asList(X)` invariably has the type `List<TypeOfX>` which you refer to as “implicit type”.

This type is not assignment compatible with your wildcard.

Let’s explain it with a simple example. Suppose, we declare a variable of type

```
List<Class<String>> list=Arrays.asList(String.class);
```

This is a list, capable of holding instances of type `Class<String>` (there is only one, i.e. `String.class`) and *nothing else*.

In contrast, a list of type

```
List<Class<? extends CharSequence>> list2;
```

is allowing us to do all of these:

```
list2.add(StringBuilder.class);
list2.add(String.class);
list2.add(CharBuffer.class);
```

therefore, it should be clear, that we can’t assign `list` to `list2` as then a list, allowing only `String.class` as it’s element, could suddenly get filled with these other `Class<? extends CharSequence>` objects.

If you want to have list, guaranteeing that the instances you will retrieve from it are of type `Class<? extends CharSequence>`, without constraining its actual type, i.e. being assignment compatible with `List<Class<String>>`, because you are not going to store new elements to the list, you can use

```
List<? extends Class<? extends CharSequence>> list3=list;// legal assignment
```

which allows

```
Class<? extends CharSequence> cl=list3.get(0);
```

but attempts to store new elements to `list3` will be rejected by the compiler, because the actual element type of is unknown (Well, except for attempts to store `null` as it is legal for all reference types).

Alternatively you can use

```
List<Class<? extends CharSequence>> list4=Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
```

Because, it is known that the returned list will reject modifications at runtime, this kind of type conversion is accepted at compile-time.

---

Of course, you can also change the type of the `Array.asList` expression. This is the right way to go, when you are going to modify the list.

```
List<Class<? extends CharSequence>> list
    = Arrays.<Class<? extends CharSequence>>asList(String.class);
```

Starting with Java 8, this type will get inferred automatically using the target type, thus the following is legal Java 8 code:

```
List<Class<? extends CharSequence>> list=Arrays.asList(String.class);
```

This also works when the `Array.asList` expression is an argument to a constructor invocation.

This all applies to `AbstractWebDriverEventListener` and `WebDriverEventListener` the same way it applies to `String` and `CharSequence`.